# In javascript, how to convert string array into array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array of string that needs to be turn into array of object with the keys **value** and **label**

```
languages: ["Arabic", "Irish"]
           0:"Arabic"
           1:"Irish"
           length: 2
```

If I wanted to make this array into an array of object like the following:

```
languages = [
    { value: 'Arabic', label: 'Arabic' }
    { value: 'Irish', label: 'Irish' }
]
```

How will I do that? Can someone please help?

Comment: `languages.map(x => ({value:x , label:x}))`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()`:

```js
var languages = ["Arabic", "Irish"];
var res = languages.map(item => ({'value':item, 'label':item}));
console.log(res);
```

You can also use `Array.forEach()` as:

```js
var languages = ["Arabic", "Irish"];
var res = [];
languages.forEach(item => res.push({'value':item, 'label':item}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad I accidently clicked on the downvote button. I was trying to click on the accepted checkmark

Comment: It's saying I have to wait 10 mins before I can accept it

Comment: @SamWhite oh you can do it later

Comment: Sure, will. Thank you once again.

Comment: Didn't realized it until you mentioned. I added it back

Comment: and will also accept it in 3 mins